# How do I work with output data from BeatifulSoup? Specifically how do I split URL and anchor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this test code to extract backlinks from webpages. But I haven`t found a good solution to extract specifically URL and anchor, as well as additional attributes of the tag.

Allow me to explain more thorough. Let`s suppose I have 3 webpages I need to check. site.com/a/, site.com/b/ and site.com/c/. For each of the webpages I have the following output with this code:

```
1. [<a data-wpel-link="external" href="https://example.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">anchor-example-1</a>]

2. [<a href="\'https://example.com/\'" rel="\'nofollow\'" target="\'_blank\'">anchor-example-2</a>]

3. [<a href="https://example.com/" rel="nofollow">anchor-example-3</a>]
```

What is the best way to split extraction so I have the following output for, let`s say, example #1?

```
Linked URL: https://example.com/
Anchor: anchor-example-1
Rel: nofollow
```

Also, as seen in the example #2 some websites tend to put some junk(?) in the code.

```
href="\'https://example.com/\'"
```

How do I get rid of things such as **\'** and other stuff that may corrupt output data at times?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

with open('input.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        check_url = line.rstrip('\n')
        data = requests.get(check_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        data.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(str(data.content), 'html.parser')
        backlink = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile('example.com')})
        print('Backlink: ', backlink, '\n')
```

Thanks in advance and have a happy holiday!

Comment: That's actually not junk in those urls. Look up escape characters to understand why that's happening.   In any case there are a lot of examples of what you are trying to do on here. Try looking up some of those and experiment. Post your attempts of you aren't able to get it and someone will help you.

Comment: Find out such characters and use str.replace() to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

try some like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<a data-wpel-link="external" href="https://example.com/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">anchor-example-1</a>
          <a href="\'https://example.com/\'" rel="\'nofollow\'" target="\'_blank\'">anchor-example-2</a>
          <a href="https://example.com/" rel="nofollow">anchor-example-3</a>
       """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for n in soup.find_all('a'):    
    print ('Linked : '+ n.get('href'))
    print ('Rel : '+''.join(n.get('rel')))
    print('Anchor : '+n.text)
```

Result :

```
Linked : https://example.com/
Rel : nofollow
Anchor : anchor-example-1
Linked : 'https://example.com/'
Rel : 'nofollow'
Anchor : anchor-example-2
Linked : https://example.com/
Rel : nofollow
Anchor : anchor-example-3
```